# multi camera samsung smart tv app

Tags: html, video, html5-video, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I am having some trouble when trying to create a multi-camera app on my samsung smart tv (sdk 5.1).

I am able to resize one video source and also placing it on any part of the tv, but when I put the second video source it never appears. It is a very basic html5 webpage with two divs in order to contain a video each. I have already tested it on my laptop web-browser and it is working fine, so I have no clue where my mistake is. Any suggestions?

I am using the auto-generated template from eclipse with the samsung sdk and this code is the only one I write:

```
<div id="vidContainer0">
    <video id="vid0" width="480" height="360" autoplay loop>
           <source src="app/video/vid0.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<div id="vidContainer1">
    <video id="vid1" width="480" height="360">
           <source src="app/video/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since its a Tv Platform so they are very specific about videos that are going to run on it, Two videos cant be run simultaneously but they can be run one after another,
eg make a mechanism that detects once one video ends then the other plays

My suggestion: Use one video tag and shuffle video on it using java-script, j-query etc

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, asap I will try this. I thought I was not able to overlay the TV signal but I could resize it. Regards

Comment: I used this same method in my apps, Dolet me know if it works and a +1 will be gud if its helped u

Comment: Right, it works perfect if they are played consecutively. Unfortunately my goal still is to play it simultaneously... I will try to make something with the PIP tool... 
Thanks for your answer!